# Cassandra Query works fine in cqlsh but gives exception via CSharpDriver

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I have the following CQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE idObject = ? AND status IN ('LEGIT', 'POTENTIAL_SPAM') ALLOW FILTERING
```

and `status` is a non-primary key column.

Now if I run this query in `cqlsh` console, it works fine but when I run this query via **CassandraCSharpDriver** its giving me the following exception:

```
IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (status) is not yet supported
```

Can someone point out why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of queries are currently not supported by the c# driver.

You need to workaround by issuing two distinct (and possibly async) queries, one for each status, and then combine the results at application level.

Comment: Why its constrained by the driver when Cassandra allows it? Any specific issue or this feature may show up in upcoming releases?

Comment: You can easily workaround as I said, and maybe it's a low priority task for such reason, I don't know.